# DrawerLayout with two drawers: Right one "jumping" when left one is opened?

Tags: android, drawerlayout

My application has a `DrawerLayout` with two drawers in it, one on the left for nav and one on the right for notifications. When the application goes through a cold start and I swipe the left drawer open, the right drawer jumps from the far left of the screen to the right.

It looks like this: http://i.imgur.com/mhoJ7MZ.gifv

As shown in the video, I've tried using `DrawerLayout`'s `isDrawerOpen` and `isDrawerVisible` methods to try to see if it actually thinks the right drawer is open when it's not (since it seems to be "closing" the drawer when the left one is opened), but I didn't get anything useful from that.

What's causing the weird jump?

My activity's XML is below, the full code is [here](https://gist.github.com/jc4p/0a1dce9a2006918f75a6).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        ...
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#ACFF0000"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="LEFT DRAWER"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/right_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:background="#AC00FF00"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="RIGHT DRAWER"
            android:textSize="24sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue comes from the `android:visibility="gone"` element on the `LinearLayout`s -- For some reason having visibility set to gone conflicts with the DrawerLayout's logic for if the view is showing or not, so it tries to hide it.

Taking that out of the XML causes everything to look the same (since `DrawerLayout` looks at the `layout_gravity` to decide which child views are drawers and hides them itself) and not have the weird jump.

Comment: Testing: This answer is superb.